# Golang check if non-existent path would be directory

Tags: go

Let's say I have a path `C:\Users\foo\bar` and I want to check if it is a directory (in the example, the path would be a directory). Is there a builtin way to do this in Go, even if the directory does not exist on disk?

Comment: That seems like an odd question. If a path does not exist, how can it be a directory? I think perhaps it's just an odd *phrasing* of the question: *I have a path. How do I distinguish between three cases: does not exist, does exist and names a file, or does exist and names a directory?* (for which the answer is to call `os.Stat` and inspect first the `err` result, and if that is nil, the other result).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231846/golang-check-if-string-is-valid-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `os.Stat`:

```
fi, err:=os.Stat(path)
if err!=nil {
  // Does not exist, or permissions issue, etc.
   pathError:=err.(*os.PathError)
   // get detalils of error if necessary
}  else if fi.IsDir() {
  // Directory
}
```

You cannot check if a non-existent path can be a directory. In your example, `bar` can be a file or a directory.

Comment: "// Does not exist" --- it might also be lack of permissions, one really need to check the err value.

Comment: Yeah, I'm silly, you're right that `bar` can be a file or directory, so there's no way to tell unless the directory/file actually exists.